# Outputting loop data to a text document in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following code: You enter a string, the computer then pulls random letters and tries to match it to the letters in your string. This repeates and with each iteration the computer gets closer to guessing your string. I would like to output the initial string entered or the 'target' and the string format of the number of iterations it took to get the correct match. I want to output this to a text document. So far the script produces a text document but does not output to it. I would like it to save the data after each iteration from the main loop. I have the working program i just need assitance with the output, any ideas on how that could be done?

Here is the progress i made:

```
import string
import random

possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + ' .,!?;:£$^%&*|'

file = open('out.txt', 'w')

again = 'Y'
while again == 'Y' or again == 'y':
    target = input("Enter your target text: ")
    attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) for i in range(len(target)))
    attemptNext = ''

    completed = False
    generation = 0
    while completed == False:
        print(attemptThis)
        attemptNext = ''
        completed = True
        for i in range(len(target)):
            if attemptThis[i] != target[i]:
                completed = False
                attemptNext += random.choice(possibleCharacters)
            else:
                attemptNext += target[i]
        generation += 1
        attemptThis = attemptNext

    genstr = str(generation)
    print("Target matched! That took " + genstr + " generation(s)")

    file.write(target)
    file.write(genstr)

    again = input("please enter Y to try again: ")

file.close()
```

Comment: Your error is not in file writing. You are not showing your whole code and it is hard to say what else it can be wrong. It should write to file just fine, unless your loop terminates before that.

Comment: Your code for writing looks fine. Note that it might not actually write to the file until file.close() is called, eg. when again != 'Y' and it exits the loop. To force writing to file once the target is matched, call ``file.flush()`` after your file.write calls.

Comment: @sashkello that is the whole code, it doesnt come up with an error in the IDE but it creates the file but does not write to it

Comment: Works just fine for me, only thing I needed to change was raw_input instead of input.

Comment: @Moritz thank you very much it works now, on a side not do you know how i could format the output to display in a certain way, because current it outputs as "hello137hello901"

Comment: @sashkello raw_input is for python 2.7 whereas you can just use input for python 3.x

Comment: Just add a line breaks & spaces where you need them.  I.e., `file.write(target + "," + genstr + "\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing both the original question and the one in the comments:

- How to write to file after each iteration of the loop: call `file.flush()` after `file.write(...)` :

  ```
  file.write(target)
  file.write(genstr)
  file.flush() # flushes the output buffer to the file
  ```
- To add a newline after each "target" and "genstring" that you write, well, add a newline to the string (or whatever other output formatting you want) :)

  ```
  file.write(target + '\n')
  file.write(genstr + '\n')
  ```

Comment: Also if you wish to keep reopening the program and continue writing to the file I suggest you use 'a' instead of 'w' in the file = open(..., 'w'). This way it appends the string to the end rather than wiping it and writing over it.